# GMSAddress placeID property missing.

Tags: ios, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I want to map GMSAddress received through GoogleMaps iOS SDK (ReverseGeoCoding) to GMaps Place. But GMSAdress class has no property called place_id. If I check web api for reverse geocoding it does contain place_id. Someone got workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

To get place_id, you would need to use Place API for that.

There are two ways you can use it, from [web service call](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/) or [Google Places API for iOS.](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/) Places API for iOS is in public beta right now.